# LongListSelector and context menu

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a collection of objects which I want to display as a list. So, I'm binding a `LongListSelector` with this collection. All the items in the collection appear in the form of list. The next thing I want to do is when the user make long press on an item so it will popup a little windows with delete,add and another options.

How i should do it? i search in a lot of places and didn't find nothing about LongListSelector and context menu

Comment: Can you put some more detail in the question? Are you just looking for a good ContextMenu? Because if so there is a control in the phone toolkit: http://phone.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have LongListSelector in my app and i want that when the user make long press on item it will popup a something like a dialog that give the user options like remove from list,play item..... It's something like the apps menu in the windowsphone home menu

Comment: Ok... so my earlier suggestion is what you are looking for! Here is a good tutorial: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-contextmenu-in-depth--part1-key-concepts-and-api

Comment: Yes, how to add this i know, but my issue is how to implement it on long press on LongListSelector item

Comment: You just hang it on each item in your list... but here they go in more detail http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/9ef36d6c-09c6-47dc-a479-cbbedeacd2e1/

Comment: Thanks, you can wrote your answer as response so i should vote for it!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a context menu... take a look at the ContextMenu control in [the Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

Then for an example on how to add this, look in the toolkit itself, but more specific for your question, you can have a look at a similar [question here...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/9ef36d6c-09c6-47dc-a479-cbbedeacd2e1/)

In short, you just add the context menu xaml on each data item of your longlistselector

Answer (score -1):

Simple code to put a context menu on a LongListSelector:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lls" LayoutMode="List" Margin="0,150,0,0">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,2,0,4" Height="105" Width="432">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="99" Height="99" BorderBrush="#FFFFC700" Background="#FFFFC700"/>
                <StackPanel Width="311" Margin="8,-7,0,0">
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding data}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding resume}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-6,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

You have to pay attention with the `ContextMenuService.ContextMenu`. If you put it out of the `StackPanel` will not work.